# Can I allow my server process to restart without killing existing connections?

Tags: python, linux

In an attempt to make my terminal based program survive longer I was told to look into forking the process off of system. I can't find much specifying a PID to which I want to spawn a new process off of.

is this possible in Linux? I am a Windows guy mainly.

My program is going to be dealing with sockets and if my application crashed then I would lose lots of information. I was under the impression that if it was forked from system the sockets would stay alive?

**EDIT:** Here is what I am trying to do. I have multiple computers that I want to communicate with. So I am building a program that lets me listen on a socket(simple). Then I will connect to it from each of my remote computers(simple).

Once I have a connection I want to open a new terminal, and use my program to start interacting with the remote computer(simple).

The questions came from this portion.. The client shell will send all traffic to the main shell who will then send it out to the remote computer. When a response is received it goes to main shell and forwards it to client shell.

The issue is keeping each client shell in the loop. I want all client shells to know who is connected to who on each client shell. So client shell 1 should tell me if I have a client shell 2, 3, 4, 5, etc and who is connected to it. This jumped into sharing resources between different processes. So I was thinking about using local sockets to send data between all these client shells. But then I ran into a problem if the main shell were to die, everything is lost. So I wanted a way to try and secure it.

If that makes sense.

Comment: Instead of self-daemonizing your process, it's much better practice to run it as a service instead. Which *specific* Linux distro are you using? If it uses systemd, or upstart, or another process supervision system, you should use that.

Comment: Kali is what I am using.

Comment: ("forking the process off of system" isn't really a phrase that makes sense in the Linux world. By "system", do you mean the user account SYSTEM on Windows?).

Comment: ...don't. Use kali, that is to say; it's not for beginners, and if you're asking this question, you're a beginner. See also [Why is Kali hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me) on [unix.se].

Comment: That said, kali *does* use systemd, and you can find documentation on writing your own service definitions at https://kali.training/topic/managing-services/

Comment: System I was thinking about Windows. I am looking into services. I just need a way to make changes to the service while it is running.

Comment: If you're running a systemd service, `systemctl restart service-name` will restart it so it picks up changes. If you actually want live code reloading, that's a larger question (that hopefully has some Q&A entries already discussing it); your application needs to be architected with that in mind.

Comment: If the service has active connections and I do a restart, will it drop those connections?

Comment: Yes, it absolutely will (drop connections at service-restart time). If you want to cut new connections over to a new version while having old connections handled by an old version, you either need to do a bunch of obscure magic to be able to pass the sockets between processes, or use socket activation such that systemd can start multiple versions of your service at once and pass inbound connections to whichever one is newer.

Comment: Thats what I thought. This wouldn't work for me as I will be making new connections.

Comment: Sounds like you want socket activation. That's still something you can do with a systemd service, it just requires a fancier kind thereof. See http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/socket-activation.html

Comment: If you have questions how to implement a service and how to make changes you should write exactly this and all necessary background information into your question. If you describe what changes you want to be able to make, someone might have a suggestion. Your process could check if a config file was modified and re-read it automatically or you cand send a signal, e.g. SIGHUP or SIGUSR1 to trigger reading the configuration. Without enough details in your question you will not get a good answer. Edit the question instead of writing many comments with additional information.

Comment: I edited more information.

Comment: This isn't really answerable as-posed -- building a service to avoid disruption during restarts (absent the low-level hackery I described above) is a matter of designing it to not have any in-memory state that can't be recovered or reconstructed, and the design factors that go into that are too broad to be something that fits in a Stack Overflow answer. Indeed, designing stateless services and protocols is something that books *literally have* been written about (in https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask, note the *"If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question"* clause).

Answer (score 4):

So, you want to be able to reload a program without losing your open socket connections?

The first thing to understand is that when a process exits, all open file descriptors are closed.  This includes socket connections.  Running as a daemon does not change that.  A process becomes a daemon by becoming independent of your terminal sesssion, so that it will continue to run when your terminal sesssion ends.  But, like any other process, when a daemon terminates for any reason (normal exit, crashed, killed, machine is restarted, etc), then all connections to it cease to exist.  BTW this is not specific to unix, Windows is the same.

So, the short answer to your question is NO, there's no way to tell unix/linux to not close your sockets when your process stops, it will close them and that's that.

The long answer is, there are a few ways to re-engineer things to get around this:

1) You can have your program `exec()` itself when you send it a special message or signal (eg `SIGHUP`).  In unix, `exec` (or its several variants), does not end or start any process, it simply loads code into the current process and starts execution.  The new code takes the place of the old within the same process.  Since the process remains the same, any open files remain open.  However you will lose any data that you had in memory, so the sockets will be open, but your program will know nothing about them.  On startup you'd have to use various system calls to discover which descriptors are open in your process and whether any of them are socket connections to clients.  One way to get around this would be to pass critical information as command line arguments or environment variables which can be passed through the `exec()` call and thus preserved for use of the new code when it starts executing.

Keep in mind that this only works when the process calls `exec` ITSELF while it is still running.  So you cannot recover from a crash or any other cause of your process ending.. your connections will be gone.  But this method does solve the problem of you wanting to load new code without losing your connections.

2) You can bypass the issue by dividing your server (master) into two processes.  The first (call it the "proxy") accepts the TCP connections from the clients and keeps them open.  The proxy can never exit, so it should be kept so simple that you'll rarely want to change that code.  The second process runs the "worker", which is the code that implements your application logic.  All the code you might want to change often should go in the worker.  Now all you need do establish interprocess communication from the proxy to the worker, and make sure that if the worker exits, there's enough information in the proxy to re-establish your application state when the worker starts up again.  In a really simple, low volume application, the mechanism can be as simple as the proxy doing a `fork()` + `exec()` of the worker each time it needs to do something.  A fancier way to do this, which I have used with good results, is a unix domain datagram (`SOCK_DGRAM`) socket.  The proxy receives messages from the clients, forwards them to the worker through the datagram socket, the worker does the work, and responds with the result back to the proxy, which in turn forwards it back to the client.  This works well because as long as the proxy is running and has opened the unix domain socket, the worker can restart at will.  Shared memory can also work as a way to communicate between proxy and worker.

3) You can use the unix domain socket along with the `sendmesg()` and `recvmsg()` functions along with the `SCM_RIGHTS` flag to pass not the client data itself, but to actually send the open socket file descriptors from the old instance to the new.  This is the only way to pass open file descriptors between unrelated processes.  Using this mechanism, there are all sorts of strategies you can implement.. for example, you could start a new instance of your master program, and have it connect (via a unix domain socket) to the old instance and transfer all the sockets over.  Then your old instance can exit.  Or, you can use the proxy/worker model, but instead of passing messages through the proxy, you can just have the proxy hand the socket descriptor to the worker via the unix domain socket between them, and then the worker can talk directly to the client using that descriptor.  Or, you could have your master send all its socket file descriptors to another "stash" process that holds on to them in case the master needs to restart.  There are all sorts of architectures possible.  Keeping in mind that the operating system just provides the ability to ship the descriptors around, all the other logic you have to code for yourself.

4) You can accept that no matter how careful you are, inevitably connections will be lost.  Networks are unreliable, programs crash sometimes, machines are restarted.  So rather than going to significant effort to make sure your connections don't close, you can instead engineer your system to recover when they inevitably do.

The simplest approach to this would be: Since your clients know who they wish to connect to, you could have your client processes run a loop where, if the connection to the master is lost for any reason, they periodically try to reconnect (let's say every 10-30 seconds), until they succeed.  So all the master has to do is to open up the rendezvous (listening) socket and wait, and the connections will be re-established from every client that is still out there running.  The client then has to re-send any information it has which is necessary to re-establish proper state in the master.

The list of connected computers can be kept in the memory of the master, there is no reason to write it to disk or anywhere else, since when the master exits (for any reason), those connections don't exist anymore.  Any client can then connect to your server (master) process and ask it for a list of clients that are connected.

Personally, I would take this last approach.  Since it seems that in your system, the connections themselves are much more valuable than the state of the master, being able to recover them in the event of a loss would be the first priority.

In any case, since it seems that the role of the master is to simply pass data back and forth among clients, this would be a good application of "asynchronous" socket I/O using the `select()` or `poll()` functions, this allows you to communicate between multiple sockets in one process without blocking.  Here's a good example of a `poll()` based server that accepts multiple connections:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzab6/poll.htm

As far as running your process "off System".. in Unix/Linux this is referred to running as a daemon.  In *ix, these processes are children of process id 1, the `init` process.. which is the first process that starts when the system starts.  You can't tell your process to become a child of `init`, this happens automatically when the existing parent exits.  All "orphaned" processes are adopted by `init`.  Since there are many easily found examples of writing a unix daemon (at this point the code you need to write to do this has become pretty standardized), I won't paste any code here, but here's one good example I found:  http://web.archive.org/web/20060603181849/http://www.linuxprofilm.com/articles/linux-daemon-howto.html#ss4.1

If your linux distribution uses `systemd` (a recent replacement for `init` in some distributions), then you can do it as a systemd service, which is systemd's idea of a daemon but they do some of the work for you (for better or for worse.. there's a lot of complaints about systemd.. wars have been fought just about)...

Comment: Some of the OP's goals (with respect to handling new connections with new code without breaking old connections) can be achieved with socket activation. That's not just a systemd feature -- [xinetd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xinetd) has been supporting it for decades (and a robust replacement therefor is included as part of [launchd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd) functionality in current MacOS); likewise [tcpsvd](http://smarden.org/ipsvd/tcpsvd.8.html) &c.

Comment: No, now that I've read all the comments, he wants to not just update the code for new connections going forward but also for existing TCP connections without losing them.  There are really only two solutions for this.  You can use a proxy process to handle the open TCP sockets (which never changes), and a "worker" process which via stdin/out or unix domain socket, does the work.. and which can be restarted by the proxy as needed.  The other way to do it would be to use sendmsg() to move connected sockets from one process to another.  Third option is to use a connectionless protocol, eg. UDP.

Comment: But I still think my answer as it stands is a good option because honestly there are so many reasons connections can get lost, you can jump through all kinds of coding hoops trying to build it so that you don't lose the connection and then you lose it anyway and have to recover.  It's simpler to design your application in a way that can reconnect after a connection loss and continue on as if it hadn't happened.  Then, no matter what the reason for the interruption, your application will be ok.

Comment: I understand, may improve my answer later when I have time.  But the prob here is that O/P was confused and thought there was a way to preserve state in a way that simply doesn't exist in unix.  So the answer to his question would just be "No, you can't", that's not what daemons do... which is very correct but isn't very helpful.  So to help him with the question we need to go back to the original problem he's trying to solve and suggest solutions which can work, I've suggested one such solution.

Comment: not *that* correct -- it's possible to pass file descriptors across a UNIX socket, and that's how programs like HAProxy support restart/upgrade without terminating existing connections. OTOH, that's not a practice it's reasonable to describe, particularly in an answer to a question that's asking about it so indirectly that anyone else who needs it will almost certainly not be able to find the question/answer pair.

Comment: ...*particularly* as being able to use that kind of practice effectively means being able to serialize and deserialize program state with respect to a given connection and pass that alongside the FD itself. That's a *lot* of background that needs to be conveyed before someone has a reasonable chance of being able to make good use of the advice given.

Comment: Well, I've added all the possibilities to the answer.  Honestly I feel it was a lot more useful answer as it was.. but god help us, this is what SO has become.

Comment: I still don't think the OP asked a great question, but this *is*, as amended, a very good answer.

Answer (score -1):

Forking from your own program, is one approach - however a much simpler and easier one is to create a service. A service is a little wrapper around your program that deals with keeping it running, restarting it if it fails and providing ways to start and stop it.

This link shows you how to write a service. Although its specifically for a web server application, the same logic can be applied to anything.

https://medium.com/@benmorel/creating-a-linux-service-with-systemd-611b5c8b91d6

Then to start the program you would write:

```
sudo systemctl start my_service_name
```

To stop it:

```
sudo systemctl stop my_service_name
```

To view its outputs:

```
sudo journalctl -u my_service_name
```

Comment: See comment-thread discussion -- the OP wants to know how to keep sockets open when modifying the code to their service. Thus, the question in full is a fair bit more complex than it looks at a glance.